# gpiozero's wait for release not working as it should

Tags: python, gpiozero, troubleshooting

I'm trying to build a program that has 2 inputs connected to 2 limit switches and each of these needs to be first opened and then closed before the function respective to each button begins. As a safety feature, I would like to block the code until the button is closed again. After looking around online I found out that the best library is gpiozero but I can't make it work :(

The code gets stuck on the block `wait_for_release()` and nothing happens when releasing the button. I don't understand why I put `btn1.wait_for_press()` goes through that but not on `wait_for_release()`.

```
    #btn1.wait_for_press()
    #print('If I uncomment wait_for_press it comes here but get stuck on the release anyway')
```

Is there a way to make this work? Even another method is appreciated! Doing `wait_for_press()` and then `wait_for_release()` doesn't work for me because I need either 1 of the 2 inputs to be pressed. Thanks in advance, here is the code:

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

btn1 = Button(12, bounce_time=0.2)
btn2= Button(20, bounce_time=0.2)

def release_btn_1():
    print('Btn1 pressed')
    #btn1.wait_for_press()
    #print('Wait for press works') 
    btn1.wait_for_release()
    print('Btn1 released')
    #function 1

def release_btn_2():
    print('Btn2 pressed')
    btn2.wait_for_release()
    print('Btn2 released')
    #function 2

btn1.when_pressed = release_btn_1
btn2.when_pressed = release_btn_2

pause()
```

Answer (score 0):

Waitforrelease (and similar) BLOCKS execution. This is precisely what it is doing. It is almost invariably WRONG to use in a program with multiple actions.

It is difficult to be more precise as it is unclear exactly what you are trying to do. Maybe another callback using onrelease may be what you want.